# how to save event Listeners

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to use shared object but i don't know
how do i save event listeners (e.g. if a mouse event has already removed before
saving).
         Let's say that "onThis" function removes a mouse event

```
    function onThis(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
    levAll.theLev.gotoAndStop(2);
    boxAll.levHit.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLevHit);
     }
    //save function
    function onSaveBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
    sharedObject.data.levData = levAll.theLev.currentFrame;
    // save that boxAll.levHit mouse event removed
        }
    //load function
    function onLoadBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
     levAll.theLev.gotoAndStop(sharedObject.data.levData);
    // load that boxAll.levHit mouse event removed
       }
```

- Amir, sorry, i just saw your answer but i don't know how to use
  your code example in a full project. I have tried the following code (see EDIT). It works although it does not seem very elegant, especially if i use it to all Listeners i have. Could you please give me an example on this? Thanks!*

  ```
      EDIT
  //public class
   var hiton:Boolean;
     //initialization
     hiton = true;

     boxHit.panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBoxPanel);
    boxHit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBoxHit);
    saveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onSaveBtn);
    loadBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLoadBtn);

         // functions
     function onBoxPanel(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
       hiton = false;
                 }

     function onBoxHit(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
        if(hiton){
        //do something
                 }
             }

   function onSaveBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
        sharedObject.data.hitData = hiton;
          }

     function onLoadBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
       hiton = sharedObject.data.hitData;
          }
  ```

Comment: You cannot store event listeners, only data types: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#data

Comment: Thank you, so maybe i should pass a var into the event Listener

Comment: What do you think, any other ideas?

Comment: I think you should start with describing your problem - your initial problem. You might pick up some hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think that my question was clear i have no any other problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You want to save event listeners in order to save them? That's your ultimate goal? So they're saved? I don't think so. You're trying to figure out some problem - some bigger problem - what is it?

Comment: i just want to save all progress of a game but i don't think we should discuss more about this here. Thanks for your time

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names and take the time to properly format and explain your code before posting a question. Your code is very difficult to read, and impossible to understand since names like "levAll", "boxAll", and "levHit" don't mean anything to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't ever need to "save" your event listeners for some buttons in a shared object in the way that you are describing; you must be approaching this from the wrong angle.

It's hard to say what you should be doing instead, since you haven't really explained what you're trying to accomplish and your variable names and function names aren't meaningful. However, in general, what you want to do is save the *state* of the object that the button interacts with, and add or remove the event listener based on that state.

```
function onThis(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    levAll.theLev.gotoAndStop(2);
    boxAll.levHit.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLevHit);
    boxAll.levHit.wasClicked = true;
 }

function onSaveBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    sharedObject.data.levData = levAll.theLev.currentFrame;
    sharedObject.data.clickedLevHit = boxAll.levHit.wasClicked;
}

function onLoadBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    hiton = sharedObject.data.hitData;
    if (!sharedObject.data.clickedLevHit) {
        boxAll.levHit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLevHit);
    }
}
```

Comment: user45623 your code works fine, only needed to change it in reverse (clickedLevHit, then remove Listener). I'm sorry for confusing (or my English), I'm new here and i tried to simplify things, with a very simple example of code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand it completely but maybe

```
var EventExists:Boolean ;
EventExists=boxAll.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK);

sharedObject.data.levData = EventExists;
```